# Launch an AsyncTask from one Activity and then launch another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

In my android app, there are two Activities A and B and there is a `Button` in A to launch B:
A -> B

I would like to launch an `AsyncTask` (which is an inner class of A) in the `onCreate()` method of A which will load some data. However, I don't want the user to be aware of that loading, that's why I launch the AsyncTask that way.
However, if A starts and the user launches B while the AsyncTask is executing, I was wondering if that would cause some Exceptions, bugs or something not right.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

An AsyncTask always keeps a reference to the Activity, so you need to cancel the AT while destroying the Activity, ie onDestroy().

[Here](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.de/2013/04/the-dark-side-of-asynctask.html) it's pretty well explained.